# How to make 2 bundles with browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I recently found out about Browserify to manage dependencies with npm.

I want to replace the three `<script>` tags inside `index.html` (jQuery, Underscore, Backbone) put them in a `bundle.js` and only include that and the `main.js` file.

Can I do this? Or should I include `main.js` in the bundle and call `browserify` everytime I edit `main.js`?

Comment: Webpack is the successor to browserify.  I would recommend to use that  instead.  If you want to go bleeding edge you can use rollup.js which will remove any unused packages at build time

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try